# how to request yahoo userInfo and contact list

Tags: javascript, yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

for calling https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo as explained [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/get-user-inf/Get-User-Info-API.html)
first I called https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token API and got access_token and after that according to guideline passed access token to userInfo API, but find not get a response.
request in postman:

```
get Method:
URL: https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo
header: Authorization : Bearer <access token>
response status 403Forbidden

post Method:
URL: https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo
header: Authorization : Bearer <access token>
response status 403Forbidden

post Method:
URL: https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo
body: {"access_token": "Bearer <access token>"}
response status 400Bad Request

{
    "error": {
        "localizedMessage": "client request is not acceptable or not supported",
        "errorId": "INVALID_INPUT",
        "message": "client request is not acceptable or not supported"
    }
}
```

so what should I do?
please also help how I can fetch the contact list?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, the problem was while I created an app in yahoo I forgot to grant access to the profile API. so after granting access, it worked fine